# Just generate SQL from ClojureQL's disj! conj! and update-in! functions

Tags: clojure, clojureql

Is there a way to just generate the sql queries from ClojureQL's disj! conj! and update-in! functions, instead of executing them directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these methods are directly executing their respective prepared statements. They are all pretty basic. For `conj!` and `update-in!`, look at `format` call in the `conj-rows` and `update-vals` functions that you can find inside the [internal](https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql/blob/master/src/clojureql/internal.clj) namespace:

```
 (format "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES (%s)"
         (to-tablename table) columns template)

 (format "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s"
         (to-tablename table) columns where)
```

For `disj!`, ClojureQL is using the `clojure.java.jdbc` library `delete-rows` function which contains:

```
  (format "DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s"
          (as-identifier table) where)
```

So basically `disj!` get the ability to use `java.jdbc`'s `with-naming-strategy` and `with-quoted-identifiers` macros for the table name while the other don't.

Comment: So if I mirror those functions I can make a to-str version, thats cool. Any idea how to do that with normal selects as well, since I just noticed they are converted to strings at the REPL, but there's no way to convert them to strings outside of *debug*.

Comment: For queries, just use the compiler directly, e.g.: `(compile (table :users) cnx)`

Comment: Thanks, found that out yesterday as well. For completeness sake, a where clause can be converted to string by just applying the str function to it e.g.: (str (where (= :id 5)))